# How to enable template function instantiation depending on container's element type

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I have defined container-checking structure and it's instantiations:

```
template <typename Container>
struct is_container : std::false_type { };

template<typename... Ts>
struct is_container<std::vector<Ts...>> : std::true_type { };

template<typename... Ts>
struct is_container<std::deque<Ts...>> : std::true_type { };

//... all other STL containers
```

It pretty much works, for function templates like this:

```
template<typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<is_container<T>::value>::type>
void container_fun(const T& cont)
{
    std::cout << "argument is clearly a container!" << std::endl;
}
```

But now, I want to allow instantiation according to container's element type. Well, something like that:

```
template<template<typename ...> class C , // container
         typename T, // container's element
         typename = typename std::enable_if<is_container<T>::value>::type> // permission
void is_element_container(const C<T>& cont)
{
    std::cout << "container's elemement is also a container!" << std::endl;
}
```

However, this leads to errors:

```
.../main.cpp:10: error: no matching function for call to 'is_element_container(std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> >&)'
     is_element_container(deq);
                             ^
.../containers.h:36: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, void>'
                  typename = typename std::enable_if<is_container<T>::value>::type>
                  ^
```

Yet, after removing third template parameter (permission checking):

```
template<template<typename ...> class C , // container
         typename T> // container's element
```

Program compiles normally, and function prints output. Why is that so?

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect. The value type of `std::deque<int>` is not a container, so your `is_element_container` function is SFINAEd out.

Comment: @TartanLlama T_T how stupid did I get nowadays... Thanks for replying :)

Comment: This would only work for nested containers.

Comment: ALso, `typename T::value_type` is probably more generic than using template template parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your code `is_element_container` requires `C` to be a container that has a container as template argument.

But the compiler complains that `std::deque<int>` is not a container of a container, which indeed isn't.

Like if you were trying to do

```
std::deque<int> cont;
is_element_container(cont);
```

but you seem that you want to do

```
std::deque<std::deque<int>> cont;
is_element_container(cont);
```

which will allow template deduction to correctly work.